# Android Studio List View in Fragment Not Display

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio-2.2

The problem I have is the List View does not show up on my fragment. I tried different suggestions from the internet, but it doesn't work.
Here is my code for MainMenuFragment.java

```
package project.foodkit.tabbed_activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;



public class MainMenuFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ListView listView;

public MainMenuFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);
    //array holding data->to be changed to list data from database
    String[] food = {"pizza", "burger", "chocolate", "ice-cream", "banana", "apple"};

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainMenu);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            food
    );
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

and the code for fragment_main_menu.xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="project.foodkit.tabbed_activity.MainMenuFragment">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainMenu" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and the mainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Shopping Cart";
            case 1:
                return "Existing ingredients";

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You're not displaying the MainMenu fragment anywhere in your activity or ViewPager. See the 'Adding a fragment to an activity' of https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: U r not using MainMenuFragment? you are using PlaceholderFragment only.

Comment: Any error in log?

Answer (score 0):

Here you used PlaceholderFragement not your MainMenuFragment

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1); <-- here is the problem
}
```

you should use your fragment instead. like

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new MainMenuFragment();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is no issue in setting listview inside MainMenuFragment();**

You have wrong code inside SectionsPagerAdapter

**replace**  `return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);` **with**  `return new MainMenuFragment();`

```
remove PlaceholderFragment from MainActivity.class
```